# In Form Script - Obtain Google Form values and pop up a dialog to form submitter

Tags: forms, validation, google-apps-script, dialog

Google Form/Sheet - When a user clicks Submit on the form, I want to check if one of the responses is already in the Google Sheet.  If it is, I want to prevent submission of the form & pop-up a message telling them their data is already assigned.

I tried adding Google Script at the spreadsheet level. But the pop-up messaging does not work, as the form is what the end-user is interacting with, not the sheet.

**Code in the sheet:**

```
//Add code to form submit on the Add Key form
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  /* a variable name with Camel Case - every new word Capital */

  /* tell it to trigger on form submit */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  /* sheet for data to goto */
  var sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses = ss.getSheetByName("SLAAssignedIdsRESPONSES"); 

  /* calls to the spreadsheet takes a lot of time - resource & same with writing to spreadsheet */
  /* better to to NOT go row by row - SLOW!!! */
  /* have it in memory in an array - faster, then modify it and spit it back out */
  /* house it in memory & read/write when have to */
  var lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getLastRow(); /* getting the last added row */  

  var StudentAssignmentExistsAlready = "";
  var SLAIdValue = "";
  var SLAIdCount = "";
  var SLAStudentName  = "";

  // Assign formulas to G and H
   // G - Count # of times SLA ID appears assigned.
  var cell = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange("G" + lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses); 
    //=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",COUNTIF(D:D,D2:D))
  cell.setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",COUNTIF(D:D,D2:D))');

  // H - Full Name
  var cell = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange("H" + lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses); 
  // IF(ISBLANK(E2:E)=FALSE,TEXT(E2:E,"00"),"")
  //=B2:B&" "&C2:C
  cell.setFormula('=B2:B&" "&C2:C');

  /*********************************************************/
  // Get the incoming SLAIdValue trying to be assigned.
  SLAIdValue = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange("D" + lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses).getValue(); 
  //SLAIdValue = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange(lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses, 3).getValue();
  Logger.log("The value of SLA ID " + SLAIdValue);

  // Get the COUNT for SLAId
  //SLAIdCount = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange(lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses, 6).getValue();
  SLAIdCount = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange("G" + lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses).getValue(); 
  Logger.log("The value of SLA ID COUNT " + SLAIdCount);

  // Get the current student assigned
  //SLAIdCount = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange(lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses, 6).getValue();
  SLAStudentName = sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses.getRange("H" + lastRow_SLAAssignedIdsResponses).getValue(); 
  Logger.log("The value of SLA Student Name " + SLAStudentName);

  /*********************************************************/
    // 1 - Look to see if the count for the current row is > 1 - If so, this SLA account is already assigned.
    // 2 - Find the SLAId already assigned for this student that is not equal to this one.

   **if (SLAIdCount >= 2 ){    
     Logger.log("Pop up response ");
   //  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  /* sheet for data to goto */
    // var sheet_SLAAssignedIdsResponses = ss.getSheetByName("SLAAssignedIdsRESPONSES");

     var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var response=sh.alert("Duplicate SLA ID Assignemnt", "Please select a different Google Id for the Non-District Student.", sh.ButtonSet.OK);

     // Proceed with deleting the LastRow, as we cannot allow this entry. 


   }**

  } // OnFormSubmit END
```

I am hoping I can pipe back a dialog box to let the form submitter that the information they are trying to assign is already assigned to someone else.

Right now, I can't get a dialog box to go back.
I need help with the google apps script for Forms.

Comment: It's not possible to interact with Google forms on the clientside.  When the user submits it's going to get submitted.  If you require this type of interaction you should consider rolling your own form via Html/Javascript. i.e. a webapp

Answer (score 0):

you do know that Google Form settings have an inbuilt option to restrict one submission per user.

Comment: However, in this case, the same user can submit more than one response.  So that doesn't help my situation. Thanks anyways.